# Unable to set embed color to RANDOM

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to create an embed with a random color using the following code. According to the [docs](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-embed-constructor), `.setColor()` should accept a [ColorResolvable](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ColorResolvable) one of which is `'RANDOM'` but i keep getting the error :

```
Unable to convert color to a number.
code : ColorConvert
```

Code :

```
const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor('RANDOM')
            .setDescription("Some description")
await interaction.reply({embeds : [embed]})
```

Comment: According to the [ColorResolvable documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/typedef/ColorResolvable) `RANDOM` in full uppercase is not an option, try `Random` instead, see if that works for you. Also what happens if you pick another option that's inside this list?

Comment: I agree with @node_modules try `Random`

Comment: @node_modules This worked thankyou so much! I wonder why in the ColorResolvable that i linked in my question they have added all string options in uppercase though then?

Comment: The documentation you've linked was placed on the `stable` branch, the documentation I linked on `main`. My guess it that they might be changing it any time soon.